# How can I convert urls to an IE bookmark

Tags: html, xml

I've wrote a program [notebook](https://github.com/HyperGroups/Mathematica/blob/master/ExplorerBookmarkClean/FavoritesOptimizer.nb) to convert chrome bookmark html to new chrome bookmark html, and it can also be imported into IE favorites.
One can test it in your own chrome bookmark html[need do backup of your own bookmark of IE and Chrome!]

The key problem is I cannot copy and move the .url files in the `/User/who/Favorites`, so I wonder whether is my html template's problem.
One can delete the broken .url folder via `remove.bat` file in my project directory.

I asked here [quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45173040/2226290%60) better format for html code.

my favorite project

so my question @this site is how can I use Mathematica generate a file, IE can import as bookmark and generate good .url files can copy and delete properly.
`html`,`rss`,`cookie` can be imported by IE favorites.
Mathematica can import RSS but cannot Export RSS directly[may be another choice].

One of my purpose is to get the .url files in different directories, it's convenient to tide up my bookmark sometimes.

Comment: What is the input, could you provide a minimal example? What are exact requirements the output must meet, at least link IE bookmarks documentation.

Comment: @Kuba see update@question, sorry for the link error, the Input of function could be one's personal chrome html. The key problem seems I do not know the exact requirements of the output.

Comment: I feel like it is your task to get those requirements and without them this question is off topic.

Comment: @Kuba Maybe I mis-understood the `exact requirements`. The exact requirements about the result of the task is the generated url files can be copied and moved.